# How to select javascript issues and their comments?

Tags: json, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I am using the SonarQube 6.4 API in order to search for issues. I do have two questions regarding it:

1. Can I filter on issues related to a language?

I tried `http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?vulnerabilities=BLOCKER&language=JAVASCRIPT` and I've got results for other languages in the json too.

2. If a tester adds a comment for a specific issue, can I have it in the json results? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to the [docs for the issue search web service](https://sonarcloud.io/web_api/api/issues/search), here are the parameters you need to make your query work right:

   - types=VUNLERABILITY
   - severities=BLOCKER
   - languages=js

To be fair, it doesn't explicitly say that 'js' is the language key for JavaScript, but it does show it in the example. The easiest way to know what the key is for a language is do to a search for its issues via the interface and then look at the resulting URL

2. To add comments to the response, you'll also need

   - additionalFields=comments

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. js key is indeed the correct one. Still, I cannot display the comment i wrote. What i did is that I logged in as an administrator, commented out an issue (ok I will fix it later) and then called the web service, but the json did not have a section for the comment I wrote

Comment: "Commented out an issue"? What does that mean in this context?

Comment: I mean that I added a comment to the issue like in the screenshot that I've added to my question up here